# How to remove a element during a range of dates

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble locating any previous posts regarding this question.

I have a div loaded on my site and i'd like to remove it based on day/month

So , i'd like to remove div#example on any dates NOT between September 7th and January 4th of each year. So i don't want to limit it to the year , as this will be a yearly occurrence.

Is this correct  ?

```
  if (/Sept 7|Oct|Nov|Dec|Jan 4/.test(new Date())) {
  } else {
    $("#example").remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try utilizing `RegExp` `/-09-0[7-9]|-09-[1-3]|-10-|-11-|-12-|-01-0[1-4]-/` , `.test()` with  `new Date().toJSON()` as argument, if result of `new Date().toJSON()` returns `true` , call `.remove()` on `#example` element

```
if (/-09-0[7-9]|-09-[1-3]|-10-|-11-|-12-|-01-0[1-4]-/.test(new Date().toJSON())) {
  $("#example").remove()
}
```

Comment: why the 2 references to september /-09-0[1-7]|-09-[2-3]|

Comment: what about the 5th and 6th ? , this seems so confusing to me , sorry , novice here

Comment: @MShack Adjusted first portion of  `RegExp` to `/-09-0[7-9]` , which should include Sep 07-Sep 09

Comment: What does the `.toJSON()` method do?

Comment: @AlexanderDixon _"This method is generally intended to, by default, usefully serialize Date objects during JSON serialization."_ See_https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON

Comment: That method is only for some browsers.  Is there an approach that will unilaterally work for all browsers?

Comment: @AlexanderDixon _"That method is only for some browsers. Is there an approach that will unilaterally work for all browsers?"_  Which browsers do not support `.toJSON` ? ; appear to be supported by all browsers , see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON#Browser_compatibility