# How to show/hide items of list respectively with interval using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I have this simple JavaScript yet:

```
$("body").children("div").each( function() {
    $(this).hide();      
});
```

The goal is:

- hide every direct children divs (completed :)
- show first direct children div
- hide that first div, show second
- hide that second div, show third etc.
- no matter how many divs there is it
- time for how long div stays displayed bassed on variable

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? All the steps are easy to research and you are expected to show your attempts to solve your problem yourself. This isn't a code writing service

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682019/body-background-based-on-hour-of-the-day-js , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763469/how-to-remove-a-element-during-a-range-of-dates/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.queue()`, `.promise()`, `.delay()`, `setTimeout()`

```
function toggleCollection(elems, duration, wait) {
    return elems.queue("toggle", $.map(elems, function(el) {
      return function(next) {
        return $(el).delay(duration).toggle(duration).promise().then(function() {
          $(this).delay(wait /* or duration */).toggle(duration)
          .promise().then(function() {
            setTimeout(next, wait)
          })
        })
      }
   })).dequeue("toggle").promise("toggle");
}

toggleCollection($("body > div").hide(), 3000, 1000 * 60 * 60)
.then(function(elems) {
  console.log("complete", elems);
  // toggle collection again
  // toggleCollection(elems, 3000, 1000 * 60 * 60)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily, first select all children except first child using [`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and hide them. Then in timer hide visible child and show next child. Note that [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) select visible element and [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) select next element.

```js
$(".list > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function(){
    $(".list > div:visible").hide().next().show();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
  <div>Child 3</div>
  <div>Child 4</div>
  <div>Child 5</div>
  <div>Child 6</div>
  <div>Child 7</div>
</div>
```